# sample code for silent post with paypal in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, paypal

i have a application where i am creating recurring profile with PayPal for monthly payment but i do not know how to manage or get payment transaction information monthly when PayPal send it to me 
can any one tell me or suggest me the sample code for silent post with PayPal in asp.net.